# Creating subplots from list of pyplot axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'd like to create a plot from a list of axes that I get from plotting functions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func():
    x = range(10)
    y = range(10)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    return plt.gca()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4)
for ax in axs:
    ax = func()
plt.show()
```

However, the plot I get is the following and has all graphs in the last subplot:
[image]

**If possible I'd like to work with plotting function as it is** and not change it. Is that possible? Many thanks!

Comment: pass the `ax` to your function and operate directly on that.

Comment: Thanks! I know this solution but would like to set the axes within the for loop and not operate on the axes object by passing it to the function. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Check [`plt.sca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.sca.html)

Comment: `plt.sca()` needs an axes as an argument. When doing `plt.sca(plt.gca())` I get the same result as described above (naturally)

Comment: Yes `plt.sca(ax)`.

Comment: Uh yeah great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) the solution could be found:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func():
    x = range(10)
    y = range(10)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    return plt.gca()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(5,3))
for ax in axs:
    plt.sca(ax)
    ax = func()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Now, I get:

[image]